# Alternate for docker sock for building images

Tags: kubernetes, docker-in-docker, kaniko

I have been using below to mount docker in my deployment file. This way From the inside of my code, I can build custom images using docker command

```
volumeMounts:
- name: dockersock
  mountPath: "/var/run/docker.sock"
volumes:
- name: dockersock
  hostPath:
    path: /var/run/docker.sock
```

Now in newer kubernetes version `privileged` and `hostPath` is disabled. Due to this on new kubernetes above will not work.

I know i have few alternatives like Kaniko for building images, but I am not sure how to use it in code and what changes I need to make in my deployment file.

Comment: What kind of `code` are you talking about? `kaniko` indeed can be helpful in such case. Have you read the [Getting Started Tutorial](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/kaniko/blob/main/docs/tutorial.md)? Do you have issues with setting up and running? Please be more precise.

Comment: I am doing docker build and docker push in code. I just want to know how to load kaniko and do a image build and deploy in code.

Comment: What have you tried so far? What the issue are you having? Please provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Tried via this https://blog.alexellis.io/quick-look-at-google-kaniko/ but it keeps complaining docker deamon is required.

Comment: At this point I can guess that `docker` is required and not a `containerd`. What is the environment?